# Why does numpy.random.normal gives some negative value in the ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution

I know that the normal distribution is always greater than 0 for any chosen value of the mean and the standard deviation.

```
>> np.random.normal(scale=0.3, size=x.shape)
[ 0.15038925 -0.34161875 -0.07159422  0.41803414  0.39900799  0.10714512
  0.5770597  -0.16351734  0.00962916  0.03901677]
```

Here the mean is 0.0 and the standard deviation is 0.3. But some values in the ndarray are negative. Am I wrong in my interpretation that normal distribution curve is always positive?

Edit:
But using `normpdf` function in matlab always give an array of positive values which I guess is the probability density function (y axis). Whereas `numpy.random.normal` gives both positive and negative values (x axis). Now this is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values generated from a Normal distribution does take negative value.

For example, for a mean 0 normal distribution. We need some positive values and negative values for the average value to be zero. Also, for the normal distribution with mean 0, it is equally likely to be positive or negative.

It actually take any real number with positive probability. You might be confused with the probability density function is always positive.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought the normal distribution is the probability density function, right? If not, then what is it? Plear clear this to me mathematically.

Comment: If you refer to this [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#/media/File:Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg), the negative value that you see is actually the x values, the values at the horizontal axis. We can see that it both positive and negative value. The vertical axis tells us how likely is it that we observe certain range of values.

Comment: First of all, why you expecting probability mean to be 0? It's clearly should be something like 0.5. If you'll make probability density distribution like this
`np.random.normal(0.5, 0.3, 1000)` You'll get positive distribution (with normal distribution).

Comment: Does numpy.random.normal function give the value of x or is it the value of normal distribution function psi(x), which is always positive?

Comment: values of x from normal distribution

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh But using `normpdf` function in matlab always give an array of positive values which I guess is the probability density function (y axis). Whereas `numpy.random.normal` gives both positive and negative values (x axis). Now this is confusing. May you clear this out to me please?

Comment: probability distribution is always nonnegative. However, the random number drawn from a distribution can be a negative value. To generate a random number from normal distribution using matlab, use [normrnd](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html)

Comment: referencing to np.random.normal in "https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html", the output is the sample (x), not the distribution (y). Therefore, the output can be negative

Answer (score 0):

referencing to np.random.normal in "https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html", the output is the sample (x), not the distribution (y). Therefore, the output can be negative.

Therefore, np.random.normal is used to do the sampling by following the normal distribution, not to randomly generate a probability value by following the normal distribution.

Answer (score -1):

Try to not expect probability mean as 0, as it makes no sense, you expecting your random event never to occur. 
Try to use something like `np.random.normal(0.5, 0.3, 1000)` to express your normal probability distribution.

Also, take a closer look at the math of [Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) to be able to construct your probability density functions easily.